# PhoneGap for Symbian - "make" package fail

Tags: java, cygwin, cordova, symbian

I am trying to make a PhoneGap package for Symbian. I've installed Cygwin with the "make" package. and when I'm typing "make on the symbian folder it gives me this error:

```
cp lib/phonegap.js framework/www/phonegap.js
cd framework/ && zip -r app.zip www/* -x www/wrt_preview_frame.html www/wrt_prev                                                   iew_main.html www/preview/ www/*.wgz
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: /usr/local/bin/C:\Program
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /usr/local/bin/C:/Program
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Can't find C:\Program on PATH.
Makefile:28: recipe for target `package' failed
make: *** [package] Error 29
```

My PhoneGap folder is directly on the C: drive and without any spaces. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have in your PATH the Symbians tools which contains the make tool, so you are not executing cygwin's make.

First check what make you are executing

```
type make
```

If you get something like this:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Symbian/tools/make
```

Then it means your PATH is wrong and you aren't executing the correct make.

Be sure to have installed the Cygwin's make package and modify your PATH so it takes the correct "make".

Comment: `make is hashed (/usr/bin/make)`

I assume that's the cygwin make path. My guess is that my windows path contains spaces within "Program Files/...", any idea how to change the path in cygwin?

Comment: Check your path in LINUX (echo $PATH) and delete every entry with a path similar to /xxx/c/Program Files (x86)/xxx.

Comment: Yup, done that, solved that. Thanks. (Note: Apparently cygwin require a manual install for zip command, solved by installing zip package from the cygwin installer)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by adding Java Runtime Environment path to Windows environment Variables after installing latest copy of cygwin. (eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin)